# How to display only one item each of multiple items in a dropdown

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core

I have a table full of items: Vessel names, container nr, type of goods, etc.
I have to make a dropdown menu with a search function. In this dropdown menu I want to display only one item out of the multiple similar values (because one vessel can occur more than once).
My problem is that I don't really know how to do that. Do I have to use JavaScript to narrow it down or use a different method in asp.net Core? I'm a bit lost..

```
<table class="plain" width="100%">
    <tbody>
        <tr class="plain">
            <td class="plain" width="100%">
                <input type="submit" name="aktie" value="Goods" class="header_button" />
            </td>
            <td>class="plain">
                <input type="button" value="⏷" class="dropbtn" onclick="myDropdown(3)">
                <div id="myDropdown3" class="dropdown-content">
                    <input onshow="focus()" onclick="event.stopPropagation()" type="text" placeholder="Search.." id="myInput3" class="myInput" onkeyup="filterFunction(3)" onkeydown="inputEvent(3,event)">
                    <div onclick="SelectValue('Vessel', '')">- All Vessels-</div>
                    @*this is the main issue. I display every item.*@
                    @foreach (var item in ViewData["Columns"] as IEnumerable<Project.Models.Folder.ClassName>)
                    {
                        <div onclick="SelectValue('Goods',@item.Goods)">@item.Goods</div>
                    }
                </div>
            </td>
        <tr>
    <tbody>
</table>
```

These are some of the JavaScript functions I made.

**myDropdown()** puts 'show' behind the dropdown-content, making it appear.

**filterFunction()** puts 'style="none" behind the items that do not have a letter that has been put in the search bar

**inputEvent()** allows you to use your arrow keys to navigate between items.

**SelectValue()** allows you to click on one of the items in the list and filters it on the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, you need a drop-down without duplicate values. You can simply pass your array to a `JavaScript` function to eliminate duplicates, and finally use it in your dropdown.

Here's a function example to remove duplicates:

```js
function removeDuplicates() {
    var cars = ["bmw", "audi", "tesla", "audi", "bmw"];
    var cars_without_duplicates = cars.filter( function( item, index, inputArray ) {
           return inputArray.indexOf(item) == index;
    });
    console.log(cars_without_duplicates); // Your console window shows the answer for this example: ["bmw","audi,"tesla"]
}
```

**NOTE:** There are several ways to remove duplicates and you can opt for any.

Comment: So if I want to get the filter to work I have to get my items in the 'var cars' so to say?

Comment: var cars is just hardcoded for example. You will have to pass your original items array to that function as soon as you get those items (say from database). Finally you can use the variable "cars_without_duplicates" to populate your drop down.